# Why the conditions $w(0)=0$ and $w(2)=\infty$ map the region $|z-1|<1$ onto the region $\Re w>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry

I want to find a linear fractional transformation which maps the region $D$ of the $z$-plane onto the region $G$ of the $w$-plane, where

$D=\{z;|z-1|<1\},~G=\{w;\Re w>0\}$

This is an exercise in my complex variable book and I can solve it by the **next section** which is about the **Mapping of the upper half-plane onto the unit disk** as follows

First we can map $G$ onto $D$ by $w=\frac{iz-i}{iz+i}+1=\frac{2iz}{iz+i}$, so we have $z=\frac{iw}{2i-iw}=\frac w{2-w}$.

Thus we conclude that $w=\frac{z}{2-z}$ maps $D$ onto $G$.

But I want to know what is the direct way in order to map $D$ onto $G$. I've seen some other books, but they've used the cross ratio, but my book hasn't said anything about the cross ratio. Could anyone help me, please?

> This is the results I've found now. Let $w=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, by the following conditions
>
> $$w(0)=0,~w(2)=\infty$$ we will obtain the map $w=\frac z{2-z}$. But I don't know why these conditions gives the correct map?

Comment: Can you "see" the Riemann sphere? And do you know that linear fractional transformation is automorphism of the Riemann sphere?

Comment: @edm No, I didn't know that they are automorphism.

Comment: Do you want the send $D$ to upper half-plane or right half-plane? The $G$ you wirte is right half-plane.

Comment: @edm If i could to send it to half plane then I can multiply by $-i$ to send it to right half-plane.

Comment: Perhaps telling us which book you are reading will help us understand what you know.

Comment: @edm An online version is available in author home page. This is the exercise 20 on page 72, http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~remi/acomplexenouv.pdf.gz

Comment: I don't understand which question are you asking exactly: are you asking why the map $z/(z-2)$ verifies the condition, or how one does find this map?

Comment: @xarles I want to find the correct map. The boxed explanation is just my try to find it. I thought that we should have these three conditions but I'm not sure why?

Comment: @xarles In fact, I can't justify that we should have $w(0)=0$ and $w(2)=\infty$. As you know, $0$ is the left point of circle and $2$ is the right point of it. That is, if $\ell$ be the left point of circle and $r$ be the right point of circle on the real axis, we should have $w(\ell)=0$ and $w(r)=\infty$. But I don't know how to justify that.

Comment: There is no a unique map verifying the properties you want (e.g. you can take $(2-z)/z$ and also verifies the property. But it seems natural to me to take the one you took: you want to send the circle $|z-1|=1$ to the line $\Re z=0$.

Comment: @xarles But $\ell$ and $r$ are just a point on real axis and not a circle?

Comment: @xarles How about $|z-i|<1$? I've chosen the points $-1-i$ and $1+i$ of the circle, so $w=\frac{z+1+i}{z-1-i}$ but I didn't arrive to $\Re w>0$?

Comment: @xarles I think the center of the circle should be on the real axis, so the correct map would be $w=\frac{(z-i)+1}{(z-i)-1}$, but I don't know why center should be on the real axis.

Comment: $-1-i$ is not in the boundary of $|z-i|<1$.

Comment: @xarles Oh yes, you are right and i've took a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to send an open disk to an open half plane, you want to send the boundary, which is the circle $|z-1|=1$ to the boundary, which is $\Re z=0$. They share a point, actually $z=0$, so it is natural to send $0$ to $0$. The opposite point to $0$ in the circle is $z=2$, and we will send it to $\infty$. Now, the centre of the circle, $z=1$, can stay fix, to be sure you send the interior of the circle to the right half plane (if you send $1$ to $-1$, then you send the disk to the opposite half plane). So you want $$w(0)=0, \ w(2)=\infty \mbox{ and } w(1)=1.$$
This three conditions give you the map you want.

Observe, however, that you can take $w+ia$ for any $a\in \mathbb R$ and the function also verifies what you want. Or even $1/w$. Or the composition with any linear fractional transformation that sends the half plane to the half plane.

EDIT: 
Another (may be better) way to construct such maps (from a disk to a disk or half-plane) is to send three points of the boundary (=circle) to three points on the boundary (circle or line): this will send the interior of the disk to either the interior or the exterior of the circle (or one of the half-planes, in the case of lines); changing the order of two of the points if necessary will give you the right map.

For example, in your case you can send $w(0)=0$, $w(2)=\infty$ and $w(i+1)=-i$. So $w(z)=-z/(2-z)$ and then $w(1)=-1$, which is not correct. But if you instead send $w(2)=-i$ and $w(i+1)=\infty$, so $w(z)=-(i+1)z/(2z-2(i+1))$, then $w(1)=(1-i)/2$ and it works. Of course it will better to send $w(0)=0$, $w(2)=\infty$ and $w(i+1)=i$, which gives your original map, but it was just to give you a different example.